# Single Excel Sheet to Multiple Sheets, based on specific column value

Tags: excel, vba, key, row

i have the following problem :

I have a spreadsheet of the type :

```
Field1    Field2     Field3    Field4
NameA     AddressA   KeyA      ValueA
NameB     AddressB   KeyA      ValueB
NameD     AddressD   KeyA      ValueD
NameE     AddressE   KeyB      ValueE
NameC     AddressC   KeyB      ValueC
NameF     AddressF   KeyC      ValueF
.... (200k entries)
```

I would like to read the worksheet, and create a number of separate excel workbooks, with only one worksheet in them, each containing ie:

```
Workbook1/Sheet1: (Workbookname ie KeyA.xlsx)
Field1    Field2     Field3    Field4
NameA     AddressA   KeyA      ValueA
NameB     AddressB   KeyA      ValueB
NameD     AddressD   KeyA      ValueD

Workbook2/Sheet1: (Workbookname ie KeyB.xlsx)
Field1    Field2     Field3    Field4
NameC     AddressC   KeyB      ValueC
NameE     AddressE   KeyB      ValueE

Workbook3/Sheet1: (Workbookname ie KeyC.xlsx)
Field1    Field2     Field3    Field4
NameF     AddressF   KeyC      ValueF
```

The first row must exist in all produced workbooks. They Field3 values are sorted, this is the logic i had in c:

```
main(excel_file)
{
   open(excel_file, r)
   header = read(excel_file)
   first_line = true

   while not eof(excel_file)
  {
  line_cur = read(excel_file)

  if first_line
  {
     office = get_office(line_cur)
     office_file = open(name=office, w)

     write(office_file, header)
     write(office_file, line_cur)

     line_prv = line_cur
     first_line = false
     continue
  }

  office_cur = get_office(line_cur)
  office_prv = get_office(line_prv)

  // If same group.
  if office_cur = office_prv
  {
     write(office_file, line_cur)

     line_prv = line_cur
     continue
  }

  // If different group.
  if office_cur != office_prv
  {
     close(office_file)
     office_file = open(name=office_cur, w)

     write(office_file, header)
     write(office_file, line_cur)

     line_prv = line_cur
     continue
  }
   }   // while end.

   close(office_file)
   close(excel_file)
}
```

Could you guys help me figure out how to implement this logic in VBA? Zero experience in it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I dont understand the negative vote. I ve seen questions being answered here which did not even supply a logic, or were described properly - and they received no negative votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your sample data (using `ActiveSheet`), this generates 3 files in current path

```
KeyA.xlsx
KeyB.xlsx
KeyC.xlsx
```

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GenerateKeyFiles()
    Const K_COL = "C"

    Dim ws As Worksheet:    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim ur As Range:        Set ur = ws.UsedRange
    Dim ck As Range:        Set ck = ur.Columns(K_COL)
    Dim arr As Variant:     arr = ck.Offset(1)
    Dim d As Object:        Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim itm As Variant, i As Long, wbp As String
    For Each itm In arr
        If Len(itm) > 0 Then d(itm) = 0
    Next
    Dim wbX As Workbook:    Set wbX = Workbooks.Add
    Dim wsX As Worksheet:   Set wsX = wbX.Worksheets(1):    wbp = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For i = 2 To wbX.Worksheets.Count
        wbX.Worksheets(i).Delete
    Next

    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ur.AutoFilter
    For Each itm In d
        ck.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=itm
        ur.Copy
        wsX.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        wsX.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll:   wsX.Cells(1).Select
        wsX.SaveAs wbp & itm, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        wsX.UsedRange.Clear
    Next
    wbX.Close SaveChanges:=False:       ur.AutoFilter
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True:   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

**`Main.xlsm`**

[image: Main]

**`KeyA.xlsx`**

[image: KeyA]

**`KeyB.xlsx`**

[image: KeyB]

**`KeyC.xlsx`**

[image: KeyC]